# An error occurs when using spark to retrieve elasticsearch data

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I want to use spark to retrieve some data from elastic-search data catalogy and I use the offical document's method then wrong here...

This is my code (using Java and JDK 1.8_221):

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark;
import scala.Tuple2;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setMaster("local");
        conf.setAppName("Spark ElasticSearch");

        conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true");
        conf.set("es.nodes", "10.245.142.213");
        conf.set("es.port", "9200");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        sc.setLogLevel("ERROR");

        JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Object>> esRDD =
                JavaEsSpark.esRDD(sc, "au_pkt_ams/au_pkt_ams");

        for(Tuple2 tuple: esRDD.collect()){
            System.out.print(tuple._1()+"-------------");
            System.out.println(tuple._2());
        }


    }
}
```

And here is the error report(All logs):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Partition$class
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsPartition.<init>(AbstractEsRDD.scala:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDD$$anonfun$getPartitions$1.apply(AbstractEsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDD$$anonfun$getPartitions$1.apply(AbstractEsRDD.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDD.getPartitions(AbstractEsRDD.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:253)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.collect$(JavaRDDLike.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Partition$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Log says **esRDD.collect()** is wrong, that they cannot get the file 'Partition.class' but the file is actully exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I found that this was a scala version incompatibility between Spark and Elastic libraries. In my case Spark libraries are included with scala 2.12 but then I realised that elasticsearch-spark connector includes only scala 2.11.

I updated Spark libraries to scala 2.11 and also changed elasticsearch-hadoop to elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11. Here is the new pom.xml entries which works fine for me.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>7.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```